# MacBook Pro 15" 2019 Dock freezes when connecting secondary display

Tags: dock

When I connect a secondary display to my MacBook Pro the Dock seems to freeze instantly and comes back alive after a few minutes.
The hub I'm using is Belkin F4U092. I've tried resetting NVRAM (cmd+alt+p+r) and it seemed to do nothing. The dock freezes again when running "killall Dock" on terminal.
Running Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Do you connect the external display after the Mac has booted up? Have you tried connecting everything (Belkin hub, ext monitor) to the Mac whilst it is shutdown, then starting it up?

Comment: I usually boot my mac whilst the display is connected. The dock flashes the apps that are set to open on start up for a moment, but then it freezes.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the Belkin (with ext monitor attached) after the Mac has booted? Do you use the Belkin's PD port to supply power to MBP?

Comment: I have tried connecting it after boot. That's when I found out the freezing problem. I don't use the PD port on the hub.